# Keeping XCOM active while doing other things on the computer

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is it possible to keep the clock moving when xcom is windowed and not the active window?

I kind of want to use it as a wall paper on one of my monitors while I work on the other that way I can do other things while xcom is running.

I know this can be done with virtual machines but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: You just want to use it as wallpaper? Can't you just take a screenshot? I'm really not sure exactly what you want to do and why.

Comment: Sorry perhaps wallpaper was the wrong choice of word. I want XCOM to run in a window as if it were the active window when it is not the active window (as I am doing other stuff).

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98623/in-civ-5-is-there-a-way-to-have-my-second-monitor-usable

Comment: I've not reached a point in the game where I've had to scan for more than a week before detecting something.

Comment: but in the mission control room times runs slowly even if your not scanning. So maybe he want to achive this. (But I anyway don't get the point since it would be the same as hitting the scan button and just let the report focused untill you are done with what ever.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to to make use of your other monitors while XCOM is running. Go to Options > Video, set mode to 'borderless window', ensure the resolution is set to your native resolution, and turn off 'lock mouse to window'.

To stop the game from pausing when it loses focus, you need to dive into `BaseEngine.ini` under `...\Steam\steamapps\common\XCom-Enemy-Unknown\Engine\Config` (if you're playing the Steam version).  Find `bPauseOnLossOfFocus` and set it to FALSE.  This is a standard Unreal Engine variable so it works on most games made using the engine.

I just tested it and it works perfectly, although after altering the .ini file you might need to change to borderless window mode again after relaunching.